# outlook 2007 not displaying buttons

Tags: html, css, outlook

I am creating an html email with

```
<input type="button">
```

as part of the email.

How can I display the buttons in Outlook 2007?

Comment: Do you have a form in your E-Mail?

Comment: As of now it is just a button , there is no form

Comment: Why would you want to? An `<input>` of type button is useless without JavaScript, and that'll never fly in an email. Even forms in general are poorly supported and should be handled by linking to a normal webpage that can open in the user's web browser.

Comment: I need to display a button in the email.

Comment: why? As David says, it is has no place in an E-Mail. If you need the visual representation of a button, use an image instead

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would have to use an image for example

`<a href="#"><img src="/button.jpg alt="Click here to learn more"></a>`

Answer (score 3):

Outlook won't be able to render the button, you will need either an image that is linked, or a text link.

edit - remember, when your dealing with HTML templates for emails, you have to code like its 1998.

Comment: Agree. And as was mentioned in the comments on the question, since javascript won't run in an Outlook e-mail a `<button>` would be useless anyway.